# Polymorphic removal of objects added to ObjectSet<TEntity> will NOT raise the IBindingList.ListChanged on ObjectSet<TEntity>.IListSource.GetList()

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, data-binding, polymorphic-associations

**OVERVIEW/DESCRIPTION**

Simple: Polymorphic removal of objects of runtime types **derived** from `TEntity` added to an `ObjectSet<TEntity>` will NOT raise the `IBindingList.ListChanged` event on the `IBindingList` object returned by the of the `ObjectSet<TEntity>.IListSource.GetList()` method.

However, removal of instances whose runtime type **match** `TEntity` are effectively notified on the `ListChanged` event.

To clarify, at all times, objects are effectively removed from the underlying collections or data views/stores, but when these objects are instances of types strictly derived from the actual `TEntity` used, the `ListChanged` event is not raised to notify of their removal.

This is simply a phenomenal BUG for the purposes of appropriate data-binding support of runtime polymorphism for collections.

**REPLICATION**

**Model Setup**

1. Table per Type Strategy.
2. Entity model mapped and validated against gemerated SQL database on Server 2012 Express.

This is the entity hierarchy (pseudo-UML):

```
FiascoEntityContext : ObjectContext
  + Foos : ObjectSet<Foo>

Foo : EntityObject
  + Id: Int32
  + Name: String

SpecialFoo : Foo
  + SpecialProperty: String
```

**Demonstration Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Objects;

namespace FiascoEF {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            using (FiascoEntityContext context = new FiascoEntityContext()) {
                //
                // add some foos
                //
                context.Foos.AddObject(new Foo { Name = "Foo1" });
                context.Foos.AddObject(new BetterFoo { Name = "BetterFoo1", SpecialProperty = "Something Special" });
                context.SaveChanges();
                //
                // show the contents
                //
                Console.WriteLine("Listing all foos:");
                foreach (var foo in context.Foos) {
                    Console.WriteLine("     Got {0}: Id={1} Name={2} (State={3})", foo, foo.Id, foo.Name, foo.EntityState);
                }
                //
                // attach handler for the ListChanged event of the IBindingList returned by context.Foos as IListSource
                // NOTE: have to do this here bacause SaveChanges() above will reset the internal IBindingList
                //
                var bindingList = (context.Foos as IListSource).GetList() as IBindingList;
                bindingList.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(bindingList_ListChanged);
                //
                // delete all foos and show state. expect the event handler above to be invoked.
                //
                Console.WriteLine("Deleting all foos:");
                foreach (var foo in context.Foos) {
                    context.Foos.DeleteObject(foo);
                    Console.WriteLine("     Deleted {0}: Id={1} Name={2} (State={3})", foo, foo.Id, foo.Name, foo.EntityState);
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        static void bindingList_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("     Event on {0}: {1}", sender, e.ListChangedType);
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Results**

```
Listing all foos:
     Got FiascoEF.Foo: Id=257 Name=Foo1 (State=Unchanged)
     Got FiascoEF.BetterFoo: Id=258 Name=BetterFoo1 (State=Unchanged)
Deleting all foos:
     Event on System.Data.Objects.ObjectView`1[FiascoEF.Foo]: ItemDeleted
     Deleted FiascoEF.Foo: Id=257 Name=Foo1 (State=Deleted)
     Event on System.Data.Objects.ObjectView`1[FiascoEF.Foo]: ItemDeleted
     Deleted FiascoEF.BetterFoo: Id=258 Name=BetterFoo1 (State=Deleted)
```

**Actual Results**

```
Listing all foos:
     Got FiascoEF.Foo: Id=257 Name=Foo1 (State=Unchanged)
     Got FiascoEF.BetterFoo: Id=258 Name=BetterFoo1 (State=Unchanged)
Deleting all foos:
     Event on System.Data.Objects.ObjectView`1[FiascoEF.Foo]: ItemDeleted
     Deleted FiascoEF.Foo: Id=257 Name=Foo1 (State=Deleted)
     Deleted FiascoEF.BetterFoo: Id=258 Name=BetterFoo1 (State=Deleted)
```

**RESEARCH**

Through reflector found that the actual `IBindingList` returned is of type `ObjectView<TElement>`, and this type delegates removal operations to an internal `IObjectViewData<TElement>`. The implementation found for that interface is `ObjectViewQueryResultData<TElement>` which defines:

```
public ListChangedEventArgs OnCollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangeEventArgs e, ObjectViewListener listener) {

    ListChangedEventArgs changeArgs = null;

    if (e.Element.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TElement)) && _bindingList.Contains((TElement) (e.Element))) {
        ...
        changeArgs = new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.ItemDeleted, ...);
        ...
    }

    return changeArgs;
}
```

The check:

```
if (e.Element.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TElement)) && ...) { ... }
```

seems bogus... probably the following was intended?

```
if (typeof(TElement).IsAssignableFrom(e.Element.GetType()) && ...) { ... }
```

Comment: Whats the question?  If you are trying to report a bug, I'd suggest reporting it to Microsoft, not here on SO.

Comment: Fair enough, bug reported — http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/749368/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fair enough, bug reported to Microsoft — http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/749368... They seem to have acknowledged the issue, but it's not clear what they will do.

Remember, we're talking about the `IBindingList` implementation retrieved by the `ObjectSet<T>` when viewed as a `IListSource` for the purposes of data-binding, so the event is expected to be fired, just as it does for the case of a homogeneous list.

I broke loose by defining a class that inherits from `ObservableCollection<T>` and wraps the `ObjectSet<T>`, then implement `IListSource` with the help of the `DbExtensions.ToBindingList<T>(this ObservableCollection<T>)` extension method.

Alternatively, I could just move on and start using the `DbContext` API entirely, but defining my own `ObservableCollection<T>` allows me to keep using `ObjectContext` for now, which is what I want.